# How to make Java game more efficient?

Tags: java, performance

I have been working on a flappy bird clone so I can get more practice programming. Everything in the game works, however the game has frame skips and lag drops, and I do not know how to make Java programs run more smoothly. Am I supposed to measure the amount of time a method takes and try to shorten that, or do I do something else? I have seen people explain how to program Java games, but there is hardly anything on improving the performance. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Hazards class

```
package entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hazards {

    public ArrayList<Horizontal> hors;
    public ArrayList<Vertical> verts;
    
    public Hazards(int width, int height, int thickness) {
        
        hors = new ArrayList<Horizontal>();
        hors.add(new Horizontal(0, 0, width, thickness));
        hors.add(new Horizontal(0, height-thickness, width, thickness));
        
        verts = new ArrayList<Vertical>();
        
    }
    
}
```

Horizontal class

```
package entity;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Horizontal {

    public int xPos, yPos, width, height;
    public Rectangle bounds;

    public Horizontal(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }
    
    public void updateBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }
    
}
```

Vertical class

```
package entity;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class Vertical {

    public int xPos, width, gapSize, gapPos;
    public boolean scoredOn = false;
    public Rectangle top, bottom;

    public Vertical(int xPos, int width, int roofHeight, int floorHeight, int gapSize) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.width = width;
    
        this.gapPos = new Random().nextInt(floorHeight - gapSize) + roofHeight;
        
        this.top = new Rectangle();
        this.bottom = new Rectangle();
        this.top.setBounds(xPos, 0, width, gapPos);
        this.bottom.setBounds(xPos, gapPos + gapSize, width, floorHeight - roofHeight + top.height + gapSize);

    }

}
```

Content class

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Content extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Engine e;
    private Rectangle bounds;

    public Content(Engine engine) {
        e = engine;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        
        // Roof and floor
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        for (int x = 0; x < e.e.hors.size(); x++) {
            bounds = e.e.hors.get(x).bounds;
            g.fillRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }
        
        // Pipes
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        for(int x = 0; x < e.e.verts.size(); x++) {
            bounds = e.e.verts.get(x).top;
            g.fillRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
            bounds = e.e.verts.get(x).bottom;
            g.fillRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }
        
        // Player
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect((int) e.p.xPos, (int) e.p.yPos, e.p.size, e.p.size);
        
        // Score
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(e.p.score), e.width/2, 80);
    }

}
```

Engine class

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import entity.Hazards;
import entity.Vertical;
import screen.TitleScreen;

public class Engine implements Runnable {

    public JFrame f;
    public String title = "Flappy Bird";
    public int width = 500, height = 500;
    public Content c;

    public boolean running = false;
    public boolean playing = false;
    public Thread t;

    public Player p;

    public Hazards e;
    
    public TitleScreen ts;
    
    public JPanel mainPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Engine e = new Engine();
                e.execute();
            }
            
        });
    }
    
    public void execute() {
        
        ts = new TitleScreen(width, height);

        e = new Hazards(width, height, 30);

        p = new Player(this);

        c = new Content(this);
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        c.setLayout(null);
        c.addKeyListener(p);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle(title);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.add(c);
        // f.add(mainPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.createBufferStrategy(2);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        c.requestFocus();
        
        //ts.setScreen(mainPanel);

        start();

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

            long lastime = System.nanoTime();
            double AmountOfTicks = 60;
            double ns = 1000000000 / AmountOfTicks;
            double delta = 0;
            int tick = 0;

            while (running) {

                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastime) / ns;
                lastime = now;

                if (delta >= 1) {
                    // Call all updates here
                    if (playing) {
                        p.updatePos();
                        tick++;
                        if (tick == 60) {
                            tick = 0;
                            p.distance += p.speed;
                            System.out.println(p.distance);
                            if ((p.distance % 4) == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Making new pipes-----------------------------------------------------");
                                e.verts.add(new Vertical(600, 10, 30, height - 30, 100));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int x = 0; x < e.verts.size(); x++) {
                            e.verts.get(x).top.x -= p.speed;
                            e.verts.get(x).bottom.x -= p.speed;
                            
                            if(e.verts.get(x).top.x<-50) {
                                e.verts.remove(x);
                                System.out.println("removed a pipe");
                            }
                            
                            if(p.xPos>e.verts.get(x).top.x && !e.verts.get(x).scoredOn) {
                                e.verts.get(x).scoredOn = true;
                                p.score++;
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }

                    mainPanel.revalidate();
                    mainPanel.repaint();
                    f.revalidate();
                    f.repaint();

                    delta--;

                }
            

        }

    }

}
```

Player class

```
package main;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Player implements KeyListener {

    public int size = 10;
    public double xPos = 50;
    public double yPos = 240;
    public double gravity = 3.4;
    public double jumpForce = 16.6;
    public double weight = 1;
    public int speed = 2;
    public int score = 0;
    public int distance = 0;

    public boolean jumping = false;
    public double jumpTime = 10;
    public int timed = 0;
    

    public Rectangle bounds, temp, top, bottom;
    
    public Engine en;

    public Player(Engine engine) {
        en = engine;
        bounds = new Rectangle((int)xPos, (int)yPos, size, size);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W && en.playing) {
            jumping = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            en.playing = !en.playing;
        }
        
        if(jumping) {
            timed = 0;
            jumpForce = 16.6;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void updatePos() {
        
        // collide with floor or ceiling
        for(int x = 0; x < en.e.hors.size(); x++) {
            temp = en.e.hors.get(x).bounds;
            if(bounds.intersects(temp)) {
                en.playing = false;
                jumping = false;
                timed = 0;
                jumpForce = 0;
                yPos = 240;
                score = 0;
                en.e.verts.clear();
                distance = 0;
                gravity = 3.8;
            }
        }
        
        // collide with pipe
        for(int x =0; x <en.e.verts.size();x++) {
            top = en.e.verts.get(x).top;
            bottom = en.e.verts.get(x).bottom;
            if(bounds.intersects(top)||bounds.intersects(bottom)) {
                en.playing = false;
                jumping = false;
                timed = 0;
                jumpForce = 0;
                yPos = 240;
                score = 0;
                gravity =3.4;
                en.e.verts.clear();
                distance = 0;
            }
        }
        
        if (jumping && en.playing) {
            gravity = 3.4;
            yPos -= jumpForce;
            jumpForce -= weight;
            if (jumpForce == 0) {
                jumping = false;
                jumpForce = 16.6;
            }
        }

        //if(!jumping && en.playing) {
            gravity += 0.1;
        //}
        
            
        System.out.println(gravity);
        yPos += gravity;
        bounds.setBounds((int)xPos, (int)yPos, size, size);

    }

}
```

Comment: I’d also avoid using KeyListener and instead make use of KeyBindings

Comment: You should check how many times your paint function is called per second, If it's called more times than your display fps you should decrease it to your fps. Also using timer should be better than calculating delta. I did a snake AI game with swing 2 years ago and it does not have problems with performance while drawing 2k snakes at same screen. Feel free too check it here but keep in mind that the code quality isn't the best over there https://github.com/Morph21/AI

Comment: While using SWing, you shouldn’t be using a `Thread` and instead prefer a Swing `Timer` - Swing is NOT thread safe. You may, however, be better off using `BufferStrategy`, which will give you complete control over the paint process

Comment: `g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());` is a waste, as `super.paintComponent` will already have done this for you